# How to update a list-of-lists using details found in another list-of-lists

Tags: python

I have a rota of employees and a list of employee details. How do I add their surname to the rota?

The actual rota has several hundred entries with many repetitions of the same person (but all employees have a different name), and the details list has about 100 entries and may not have one or two of the employees on it.

The code below works but loops through all details for every rota entry. Is there a more efficient way (using Python 2.7) and can I add '?' if the name is not found?

```
rota = [['Paul'], ['Paul'], ['Steve'], ['Steve'], ['Steve'], ['Simon'], ['Bob'], ['Steve']]
details = [['Paul', 'Smith'], ['Simon', 'Says'], ['Steve', 'Brown']]

for eachName in rota:
    for eachEmployee in details:
        if eachName[0] == eachEmployee[0]:
            eachName.append(eachEmployee[1])

print rota
```

(Sorry if this is confusing, its the simplest example I could think of!)

Answer (score 2):

You simply need to convert `details` to a dict:

```
rota = [['Paul'], ['Paul'], ['Steve'], ['Steve'], ['Steve'], ['Simon'], ['Bob'], ['Steve']]
details = dict([['Paul', 'Smith'], ['Simon', 'Says'], ['Steve', 'Brown']])

for eachName in rota:
    surname = details.get(eachName[0])
    if surname:
        eachName.append(surname)

print(rota)
```

Note that there's only one `for` loop left, and the processing should be much faster.

The values in your dict could be tuples with multiple attributes :

```
>>> details = dict([['Paul', ('Smith', 32)], ['Simon', ('Says', 20)], ['Steve', ('Brown', 52)]])
>>> details
{'Steve': ('Brown', 52), 'Paul': ('Smith', 32), 'Simon': ('Says', 20)}
```

Comment: Brilliant! Unfortunately I over-simplified my example as there are more than just two details for each employee, but it must be easy enough to duplicate the list with just the two details I need. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can efficiently do this with list and dictionary comprehensions, with a caveat -- all the keys must be in both lists. Note that the key mismatch of "Bob" has been commented out from your original code.

```
>>> rota = [['Paul'], ['Paul'], ['Steve'], ['Steve'], ['Steve'], ['Simon']] #, ['Bob']]
>>> details = [['Paul', 'Smith'], ['Simon', 'Says'], ['Steve', 'Brown']]
>>> d = {n[0]: n[1] for n in details}
>>> [list([n[0],d[n[0]]]) for n in rota]
[['Paul', 'Smith'], ['Paul', 'Smith'], ['Steve', 'Brown'], ['Steve', 'Brown'], ['Steve', 'Brown'], ['Simon', 'Says']]
>>>
```

Comment: Yikes! This doesn't work if there's a key error. Thanks for the feedback.